# Jackson throwing "msg":"Unrecognized field \"numeratorType\" while de serializing the JSON into POJO

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have created a JSON Object from POJO classes with one of them containing the following code

```
@JsonProperty("numeratorType")
private BigDecimal numerator;
```

I am again converting the same JSON Object (String) to POJO with the following code

```
JSONObject test = new JSONObject(/**JSON String***/);
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
DataResponse user = mapper.readValue(test.toString(), DataResponse.class); <--error is thrown in this line
```

but Jackson is throwing following error while doing so

```
**Jackson throwing "msg":"Unrecognized field \"numeratorType\"**
```

I tried to find a valid reason for the same and understood that somehow Jackson is not able to find proper setter for the same property. 
I am not sure on how to handle this situation. Any thoughts?

Comment: Why do you use JSONObject`? Just provide `/**JSON String***/` to `readValue` directly.

Comment: True, that can be done to save some extra computation. But that wont resolve the problem I am facing.

Comment: Could you show whole `JSON` and `POJO`? It would be the best if this problem could be reproducible.

Comment: Followed you on Github :) I will connect to you on mail/separately.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated answer**

It should be as follows :

```
DataResponse user = mapper.readValue(test.toString(), new TypeReference<DataResponse>(){});
```

If, you have a list of `JSONs`, it could be as following :

```
DataResponse user = mapper.readValue(test.toString(), new TypeReference<List<DataResponse>>(){});
```

Comment: TypeReference comes from  com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type ?

Comment: Yes @Rishi, import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;

Comment: Also, I agree with @Ashish-Bakwad's answer. Jackson does has a limitation of naming convention of properties.

Comment: I am not able to do new TypeReference<DataResponse>() getting "can not instantiate "TypeReference<DataResponse>". Does POJO need to implement some interface to do this?

Comment: It will be" TypeReference<DataResponse>{}". Sorry, my bad. I'll update in answer. Please try with this, it is working or not.

Comment: now "The method readValue(String, Class<T>) in the type ObjectMapper is not applicable for the arguments (String, new TypeReference<DataResponse>(){})"

Answer (score 1):

Add another field as a numeratorType and add setter getter methods for it and try.

```
    private BigDecimal numeratorType;

    public BigDecimal setNumeratorType(BigDecimal numeratorType) {
         this.numeratorType = numeratorType;

    }

    public BigDecimal getNumeratorType() {
        return this.numeratorType 

    }
```

Comment: That seems like a workaround. Is this a standard way to solve it?

Comment: Actually, You don't need to use @JsonProperty("numeratorType") annotation. Unless variable names are not as per java standard.

Comment: actually It's like Swagger API Doc-->POJO<--DataBase Stored proc. So Stored proc sets in a variable numerator while as per API doc it needs to be in JSON with name numeratorType. Hence I added.